# How to run a cypher script file from Terminal with the cypher-shell neo4j command?

Tags: csv, neo4j, terminal, cypher, cypher-shell

I have a cypher script file and I would like to run it directly.

All answers I could find on SO to the best of my knowledge use the command `neo4j-shell` which in my version (Neo4j server 3.5.5) seems to be deprecated and substituted with the command `cyphershell`.

Using the command `sudo ./neo4j-community-3.5.5/bin/cypher-shell --help` I got the following instructions.

> usage: cypher-shell [-h] [-a ADDRESS] [-u USERNAME] [-p PASSWORD]
>   [--encryption {true,false}]
>                       [--format {auto,verbose,plain}] [--debug] [--non-interactive] [--sample-rows SAMPLE-ROWS]
>                       [--wrap {true,false}] [-v] [--driver-version] [--fail-fast | --fail-at-end] [cypher]
>
> A command line shell  where  you  can  execute  Cypher  against  an 
>   instance  of  Neo4j.  By  default the shell is interactive but you can
>   use it for scripting by  passing  cypher  directly  on the command
>   line or by piping a file with cypher statements (requires Powershell
>   on Windows).

My file is the following which tries to create a graph from csv files and it comes from the book "Graph Algorithms".

```
WITH "https://github.com/neo4j-graph-analytics/book/raw/master/data" AS base 
WITH base + "transport-nodes.csv" AS uri
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM uri AS row
MERGE (place:Place {id:row.id})
SET place.latitude = toFloat(row.latitude),
  place.longitude = toFloat(row.latitude),
  place.population = toInteger(row.population)

WITH "https://github.com/neo4j-graph-analytics/book/raw/master/data/" AS base 
WITH base + "transport-relationships.csv" AS uri
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM uri AS row
MATCH (origin:Place {id: row.src})
MATCH (destination:Place {id: row.dst})
MERGE (origin)-[:EROAD {distance: toInteger(row.cost)}]->(destination)
```

When I try to pass the file directly with the command:

```
sudo ./neo4j-community-3.5.5/bin/cypher-shell neo_4.cypher
```

first it asks for username and password but after typing the correct password (the wrong password results in the error `The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.`) I get the error:

```
Invalid input 'n': expected <init> (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"neo_4.cypher"
 ^
```

When I try piping with the command:

```
 sudo cat neo_4.cypher| sudo ./neo4j-community-3.5.5/bin/cypher-shell -u usr -p 'pwd'
```

no output is generated and no graph either.

How to run a cypher script file with the neo4j command `cypher-shell`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the cypher file: each line should end with a semicolon: `;`. I still need `sudo` to run the program.

The file taken from the book seems to contain other errors as well actually.

Answer (score 11):

Use `cypher-shell -f yourscriptname`. Check with `--help` for more description.

Answer (score 5):

I think the key is here:

```
cypher-shell -- help

... Stuff deleted

positional arguments:
  cypher                 an optional string of cypher to execute and then exit
```

This means that the paremeter is actual cypher code, not a file name. Thus, this works:

```sh
GMc@linux-ihon:~> cypher-shell "match(n) return n;"
username: neo4j
password: ****
+-----------------------------+
| n                           |
+-----------------------------+
| (:Job {jobName: "Job01"})   |
| (:Job {jobName: "Job02"})   |
```

But this doesn't (because the text "neo_4.cypher" isn't a valid cypher query)

```sh
cypher-shell neo_4.cypher
```

The help also says:

```sh
example of piping a file:
  cat some-cypher.txt | cypher-shell
```

So:

```sh
cat neo_4.cypher | cypher-shell
```

should work. Possibly your problem is all of the sudo's. Specifically the cat ... | sudo cypher-shell. It is possible that sudo is protecting cypher-shell from some arbitrary input (although it doesn't seem to do so on my system).

If you really need to use sudo to run cypher, try using the following:

```sh
sudo cypher-shell arguments_as_needed < neo_4.cypher
```

Oh, also, your script doesn't have a return, so it probably won't display any data, but you should still see the summary reports of records loaded.

Perhaps try something simpler first such as a simple match ... return ... query in your script.

Oh, and don't forget to terminate the cypher query with a semi-colon!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with a simpler command with a result. Apparently I need the `sudo` even for a simple commands such as `sudo ./neo4j-community-3.5.5/bin/cypher-shell "MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 25;"` otherwise no output is generated. Also your example `sudo cypher-shell arguments_as_needed < neo_4.cypher` is not outputting anything.

Comment: I wonder if there is a bug? My system does the same thing. There is this similar bug report [here](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-shell/issues/100). It is not the exact same issue (my file does not have BOM characters) but it is similar. I will keep playing with it to see if I can find out more.

Comment: I thanks for your help. The problem is that for cypher each line must end with `;`. I still need `sudo` though but that's not a problem.

Comment: After sleeping on it I came to the same realisation that I had (once again) forgotten the trailing semi-colon on my query in the text file. Once added, it works as expected. I'll add that to the answer :-)

Comment: @Francesco_Boi If any of these answers has helped you, could you please accept one of them as the answer and "up vote" it. Simply click the little grey "check mark" next to the answer that you think has helped you the most.

Comment: I upvoted yours when you posted: in fact it has score +1 (by me). What worked though is explained in my answer.